# Makefile circular dependency

Tags: c, makefile, dependencies, circular-dependency

Here is my Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all homework1
CFLAGS= -g -O0 -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-function
LDFLAGS= -lm

all : homework1

homework1 : program.tab.o program.lex.o
%.o : %.c
    gcc -o$@ -c $(CFLAGS) $<
%.lex.c : %.lex %.tab.h
    flex -o$@ $<
%.tab.c %.tab.h : %.y
    bison --verbose -o$@ -d $<
```

Whenever I try to compile, I get the warning `make: Circular program.lex <- program.lex.o dependency dropped.` I don't see how `program.lex` is dependent on `program.lex.o` at all in the makefile. I see how the dependency tree is about 4 layers deep, but it doesn't look circular.

How can I improve my makefile?

Comment: Not only is your question tagged as "homework" (without anyone asking you to), but your executable is also named "homework". Just an observation! No comment :D

Comment: It is homework. Of course, the homework is to write the flex and bison files, not the makefile. The makefile should be the easy part :P

Comment: Makefiles are never easy, in my experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@aaa carp is correct that is an implicit rule, but it's not one of the `LEX` rules, because they build `N.c` or `N.r` from `N.l`, and this is a rule that's building `N` from `N.o`. That looks to me like the "Linking a single object file" rule, described in `info (make) Catalogue of Rules`. Renaming your `.lex` files to `.l` files will fix this problem.

Also: running `flex`, I don't think you really need the `.tab.h` file to build the lexer source. Try this instead:

```
%.l.c: %.l
    flex -o$@ $<
program.l.o: program.tab.h
```

This will add the extra dependency to `program.l.o`.

Comment: Thanks! Fixes the problem. Wish I knew all of these implicit rules. Do you know if I can turn them off?

Comment: @Mike: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules is the catalogue of all rules. `make -r` will run without implicit rules, but I don't remember if that works as a setting in the `MAKEFLAGS` variable or if it must be specified on the command line.

Answer (score 10):

The trouble is that there is an implicit rule in Make (well, in GNUMake anyway) for linking a single object file to build en executable. Your makefile says nothing about how to build `program.lex`, so Make falls back on the implicit rule to build it from `program.lex.o`.

Since your your layout seems to depend on having `program.lex` to begin with, you can suppress the implicit rule by adding your own rule for `program.lex` (which does nothing):

```
program.lex:;
```

Comment: Nice trick to silence the implicit rule. I hadn't seen that before.

Answer (score 6):

run make with -d:

```
Considering target file `all'.
 File `all' does not exist.
  Considering target file `homework1'.
   File `homework1' does not exist.
    Considering target file `program.lex.o'.
     File `program.lex.o' does not exist.
     Looking for an implicit rule for `program.lex.o'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `program.lex'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `program.lex.c'.
     Found an implicit rule for `program.lex.o'.
      Considering target file `program.lex.c'.
       Looking for an implicit rule for `program.lex.c'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem `program'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite `program.lex'.
       Found an implicit rule for `program.lex.c'.
        Considering target file `program.lex'.
         Looking for an implicit rule for `program.lex'.
         Trying pattern rule with stem `program.lex'.
         Trying implicit prerequisite `program.lex.o'.
         Found an implicit rule for `program.lex'.
make: Circular program.lex <- program.lex.o dependency dropped.
```

there is implicit link rule which gets invoked, not lex I originally
put down

get rid off ".lex.*" extensions

Comment: No - it's the rule that tries to link programs made from a single object file.

Answer (score 0):

My immediate reaction was that you need an action after the rule that says `homework1: program.tab.o program.lex.o`:

```
 homework1:  program.tab.o program.lex.o
         ${CC} -o $@ program.tab.o program.lex.o ${LDFLAGS}
```

However, since you've also marked `homework1` as `.PHONY`, maybe you are not ready to link the program yet.  But your problem reproduces...

Conventionally, the source for Lex (or Flex) is kept in a `.l` file, not in a `.lex` file, so I changed the makefile to:

```
.PHONY: all homework1
CFLAGS= -g -O0 -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-function
LDFLAGS= -lm

all : homework1

homework1 : program.tab.o program.lex.o

%.o : %.c
    gcc -o $@ -c $(CFLAGS) $<
%.lex.c : %.l %.tab.h
    flex -o $@ $<
%.tab.c %.tab.h : %.y
    bison --verbose -o $@ -d $<
```

The warning message goes away. (I created your environment by using '`touch program.lex program.y`' initially; I then moved `program.lex` to `program.l`).

However, I'm still not quite sure what is going on in the broken version - but it probably does revolve around implicit rules as suggested by @Beta.

Comment: The "breakage" in the "broken version" is from the "Linking a single object file" rule (`foo.o` -> `foo`).