# Makefile circular dependency with Windows resource files

Tags: makefile, circular-dependency, win32gui, windres

There have been several questions regarding *circular dependencies* being dropping when running a Makefile ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324697/makefile-circular-dependency-dropped) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674019/makefile-circular-dependency)), however, I am still a bit confused as to why they are occurring.

For example, I am trying to compile a Win32 GUI program that contains resource files ([from this tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/menus.html)). These resource files are compiled to object files through the `windres` command, so they can be linked to the final executable ([as described here](https://fragglet.livejournal.com/4448.html)):

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -mwindows
DEPS = resource.h
OBJ = menu_one.o $(patsubst %.rc,%.rc.o,$(wildcard *.rc))

all: menu_one

%.rc.o: %.rc
    windres $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

menu_one: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
```

The command `$(patsubst %.rc,%.rc.o,$(wildcard *.rc))` takes all the resource files ending in `.rc` and slaps a `.o` extension onto them (e.g. `resource.rc.o`).

When I run this, everything seems to work and I get a working executable, however, Make outputs the following:

```
gcc -c menu_one.c -o menu_one.o -mwindows
make: Circular menu_one.rc <- menu_one.rc.o dependency dropped.
windres menu_one.rc -o menu_one.rc.o
gcc menu_one.o menu_one.rc.o -o menu_one -mwindows
```

Is this *circular dependency* occurring because I technically have two `.o` rules? In other words, **how can I correct this circular dependency?**

---

## Edit 1:

I tried following what [@MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328149/makefile-circular-dependency-with-windows-resource-files#answer-55328252) said, however, this still created a *circular dependency* with Make. After some more Googling, I came across [the following page](https://faculty.cs.byu.edu/~rodham/cs240/make-tutorial.html). Towards the very bottom there is a section titled "*Circular File Dependencies*." This got me thinking about the output from Make:

```
make: Circular menu_one.rc <- menu_one.rc.o dependency dropped.
```

It looks to be that the `rc` suffix is creating this dependency - even though it is not part of the file extension of the outputted object file (i.e. `file.rc.o`). If I change the output file suffix to be `.res.o`, the *circular dependency* goes away entirely:

```
...
RESOBJ = $(patsubst %.rc,%.res.o,$(wildcard *.rc))
OBJ = menu_one.o $(RESOBJ)
...
%.res.o: %.rc
    windres $^ -o $@
...
```

This sparks a very similar question, **if I wanted to use the previous suffix `.rc.o`, how would you accomplish this?** Is it possible?

## Edit 2:

[@MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328149/makefile-circular-dependency-with-windows-resource-files#answer-55328252)'s suggestion of using a [match-anything rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html) worked perfectly with correcting the problem. This now allows me to use the `.rc.o` suffix ending. See [@MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328149/makefile-circular-dependency-with-windows-resource-files#answer-55328252)'s updated answer below.

Comment: I discussed below in my updated answer why you are getting this circular reference (what make is doing) and how to resolve it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to not name your `windres` output files with a `.o` extension.  If you choose a different extension, you won't have this problem.

Another way is to use [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html) for the `windres` targets:

```
RCOBJ := $(patsubst %.rc,%.rc.o,$(wildcard *.rc))
OBJ = menu_one.o $(RCOBJ)

  ...
$(RCOBJ) : %.rc.o : %.rc
        windres $^ -o $@
```

Since static pattern rules are shorthand for creating explicit rules, and are not implicit rules, they don't participate in searches so make won't come up with a circular dependency.

**ETA**

OK I created your example locally.  Using `make -d` we can see what happens: make needs to build `menu_one.rc.o` and it finds our rule with a prerequisite of `menu_one.rc`.  Then it needs to see if it can rebuild `manu_one.rc`, and it find the generic pattern rule for building executables:

```
%: %.o ; ...
```

Matching this pattern with a target of `menu_one.rc` gives a prerequisite of `menu_one.rc.o`, and you have a loop.

What you need to do is notify make that the `*.rc` files are source files and make shouldn't try to build them.  You can do this by declaring a *terminal rule*.  There is a comprehensive discussion of the intricacies of dealing with [match-anything rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html) (rules with a target of `%` alone, which matches any target) in the GNU make manual.

Add this to inform make that your `.rc` files are terminal (that is, they can't be built from something else):

```
%.rc:
```

Comment: I added the new variable `RCOBJ` and added the static pattern rule for the `$(RCOBJ)` list of files, however, I am still getting a circular dependency error. I did remove my `%.rc.o: %.rc` rule, but I kept my `%.o: %.c $(DEPS)` rule and `menu_one: $(OBJ)` rule as is. Did I miss something?